# Mysterious "Page not found" on every page load for authenticated users

Tags: 7, media

I recently migrated my site to a new server, and restructured the urls, etc... so naturally there are quite a few 404's out there from other sites linking to old content. So far, so normal.

But among the page not founds, I'm getting something really bizarre: as far as I can tell, every single page load of the site **by authenticated users** is generating one particular "page not found" error for a file at location sites/default/files/stripes54-navywhite.jpg.

[image: screenshot]

*Every page load for every authenticated user*.

[image: screenshot]

Now this file does not exist. Nor are there any links on the site to it (the file name is familiar: we may have had a file at that location at some point in the past, on the old site).

I have searched page source, I have searched through the contents of all my site files, I have searched my complete db using phpmyadmin. There is no reference to this file anywhere, as far as I can tell.

So what could possibly be causing this? Where is this file mysteriously being referenced? Watchdog is giving me no help here.

My only clue at the moment is that this page not found seems to ONLY be triggered by authenticated users: not seeing any anonymous users triggering it.

Does anyone have any earthly idea what might be going on here? A big thanks to anyone who can help!

I'm even getting this error generated by admin pages, which use a separate admin theme. For example, when browsing my database log.

[image: screenshot]

There is one entry in the file_managed table where origname is stripes54-navywhite.jpg. Unfortunately, this doesn't really shed much light on the problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you are searching for content search by parts, search for navywhite only you might get something in content.

Comment: Okay, there is one entry in file_managed db table where origname = stripes54-navywhite.jpg (see [phpmyadmin entry](http://i.imgur.com/9Zo4p.png). Unfortunately I don't think this sheds much light on anything...

Comment: Ok that pic was uploaded from content/user profile perhaps. To debug : shortest way : 1 : upload a dummy pic of same name, see if pic comes up in front, dig deeper to check the module/content assosciated with it : 2 : Check corresponding file_id check node/content tables for that file_id. EDIT : Saw the image now, does that value in URI column ring any bells ?

Comment: Checked fid, current uri, nid, etc... still nothing. That node exists, and that file exists, but there's still nothing at sites/default/files/stripes54-navywhite.jpg, and still nothing linking there...

Comment: Did you try uploading a pic with same name ? Try this if it comes up in front end then you can debug further.

Comment: What do you mean by "comes up in front"? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, this appears to be an issue with [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com). Disabled it, and the problem went away... re-enabled it, and the problem returned, but with a different image url!

Yet further investigation shows Cloudflare's Website preloader to be the culprit. So nothing to do with Drupal.